# Unbound States of the 1D Finite Potential Well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy, quantum-states

Edit: After writing a Python code to numerically solve the constraint problem on the coefficients with Gauss-Jordan elimination, it seems that the biggest problem was that I was treating the coefficients $C$ and $D$ as identical for wave functions on each side of the well. This simply isn't true for solutions of any parity. The coefficient $D$ is equal in magnitude but opposite sign on opposite sides of the well for the even solutions, while the coefficient $C$ is equal in magnitude but opposite in sign for the odd wave function on either side of the well. In retrospect, this makes perfect sense.

## Background

The well-known finite potential well is an extension of the "particle-in-a-box" or PIAB model that is often students' first introduction to quantum mechanics problems wherein the depth of the potential well is some finite value $V_0$. There are a variety of approaches to solving for the bound states, most of which revolve around parity and a clever combination of equations to give two transcendental formulas for the energies of the even and odd states. Numerically solving for the quantized energies then allows one to find the coefficients of the various wave function pieces by normalizing the wave function. Much of this is found is standard textbooks on the subject like that of Cohen-Tannoudji, Diu, and Laloe.

## The Problem

My problem is what happens when one tries to characterize the unbound states of the 1D finite potential well. Specifically, I wish to show that the energies of the unbound states are actually continuous by showing an appropriate wave function can be generated for any arbitrary $E$. By letting $E > V_0$ for the unbound states, we obtain a new form of the solutions outside the well,
\begin{align*}
\psi_\text{outside} (x) &= \alpha e^{ikx} + \beta e^{-ikx} & k &= \frac{\sqrt{2m(E-V_0)}}{\hbar}
\end{align*}
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary constants. If we use Euler's formula, this can be cast in terms of simple sines and cosines, giving,
\begin{gather*}
\psi_\text{outside} (x) = C \cos(kx) + D \sin (kx) 
\end{gather*}
The wave function for the inside of the well is exactly the same as it was for the bound states,
\begin{align*}
\psi_\text{inside} (x) &= A \cos(nx) + B \sin (nx)  & n &= \frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}
\end{align*}
At this point, it is clear that the wave function cannot be normalized, as the function simply oscillates over all of space. My question is about whether there is an accepted method for applying the boundary conditions at the edges of the well $\left(-\frac{L}{2} \text{ and } \frac{L}{2} \right)$ such that the resulting wave function is continuous and has a continuous derivative. If there is a source that outlines the method that could be used to explain a functioning approach, that would constitute an answer to this question.

## My Approach and Attempted Results

My approach was to assume that the functions once again were either even or odd,
\begin{align*}
\psi_{inside, even} &= A \cos(nx) & \psi_{inside, odd} &= B \sin(nx)
\end{align*}
and set $A=B=1$ since the wavefunction cannot be normalized anyway. Then, applying the boundary conditions at the right edge of the well $\left( \frac{L}{2} \right)$ and combining equations leads to apparent answers for the coefficients of the even and odd $\psi_{outside}$ states. Disappointingly, however, these solutions seem to outright fail. I cannot completely rule out a simple algebra error, but my derivation has been carried out three times and yields the following formulas,
\begin{align*}
C_{even} &= \frac{n\sin \left( \frac{nL}{2} \right) + k\cos \left( \frac{nL}{2} \right)}{k \sin\left( \frac{kL}{2} \right) + k\cos \left( \frac{kL}{2} \right) } & A_{even} &= 1 \\
D_{even} &= \frac{ k\cos \left( \frac{nL}{2} \right) - n\sin \left( \frac{nL}{2} \right)}{k\sin\left( \frac{kL}{2} \right) + k\cos \left( \frac{kL}{2} \right) } & B_{even} &= 0 \\
C_{odd} &= \frac{ k\sin \left( \frac{nL}{2} \right) - n\cos \left( \frac{nL}{2} \right) }{k \sin\left( \frac{kL}{2} \right) + k\cos \left( \frac{kL}{2} \right)} & A_{odd} &= 0 \\
D_{odd} &= \frac{ k\sin \left( \frac{nL}{2} \right) + n\cos \left( \frac{nL}{2} \right) }{k\sin\left( \frac{kL}{2} \right) + k\cos \left( \frac{kL}{2} \right)} & B_{odd} &= 1 
\end{align*}
Just plotting these functions, however, shows that the outside functions end up having values far outside the bounds of $\psi_{inside}$ with my choice of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You may want to consider using a different letter, such as $k$, rather than $n$ and $m$. In particular, $m= \frac{\sqrt{2m(E-V_0)}}{\hbar}$ seems problematic :)

Comment: That’s completely fair. It never occurred to me that was confusing because my simulations of the solutions all set the mass to 1!

Comment: The overall amplitude-squared outside the well will be $C^2 + D^2$, and it looks like those expressions will simplify somewhat if you calculate them.  Might be worth a look to get a sense of whether there are parameters for which exterior solution is particularly large or small.  (In particular, unless I'm mistaken, the denominator will diverge when $k L = \pi, 3 \pi, 5 \pi, ...$)

Comment: Correction: $kL = 3 \pi / 2, 7 \pi/2, 11\pi/2,...$

Comment: (1/2) Note that *most* of the time this problem is treated, we are considering the physical situation of *scattering*. In that case, we shoot particles in from one side (say, the left), and we see what happens. For that reason, on the left, we get left and right moving waves, but on the *right* of the well, we only include the *right*-moving waves.  This leaves six unknowns: 5 amplitudes and 1 energy. Since there are four "boundary" conditions (continuity of $\psi$ and $\psi'$ at the ends of the well), we can solve for four of the amplitudes in terms of the fifth.

Comment: (2/2) Usually, we solve in terms of the incident amplitude (right-moving wave to the left of the well). Crucially, this leaves the incoming amplitude and energy unspecified, which makes sense if we are modeling a scattering experiment.  The experimenter can control the individual energy of the particles *and* the incident flux (i.e., how many particles we're shooting per unit time, essentially). In any case, we get a continuum of energies, which *makes sense physically* because of this experimental knob. Incidentally, the resulting wave functions are neither even nor odd.

Comment: I actually have seen the scattering problem and didn’t mention it. It’s a famously bizarre case where you can have a particle “bounce back” off of a hole, which is wildly non-classical!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct ansatz for a simultaneous eigenfunction of the Hamilton operator and the paritity operator with energy $E>V_0$ and even parity is given by $$\psi_E^+(x) = \begin{cases} C \cos kx +D \sin kx & \text{for} \;x \lt -L/2 \\[2pt] A \cos n x & \text{for}\; -L/2 \le x \le L/2 \\[2pt] C \cos kx -D \sin kx & \text{for} \;x\gt L/2 \end{cases}, $$ where $\psi_E^+(-x)= \psi_E^+(x)$. The coefficients $A$, $B$, $C$ are further restricted by the continuity of $\psi_E^+$ and  its first derivative at the points $x= \pm L/2$. Expressing $C$ and $D$ in terms of $A$, one finds the nice result $$\begin{align} C&= A\left(\frac{n}{k}\,\sin\frac{n L}{2}\,\sin{\frac{kL}{2}}+ \cos \frac{n L}{2} \, \cos\frac{k L}{2}   \right), \\[2pt] D&= A\left(\frac{n}{k} \, \sin \frac{nL}{2}\, \cos\frac{kL}{2} -\cos \frac{nL}{2} \, \sin \frac{kL}{2}  \right).      \end{align}$$

Analogously, an eigenfunction with odd parity has the form $$\psi_E^-(x) = \begin{cases} C \cos kx +D \sin kx & \text{for} \; x\lt -L/2 \\[2pt] B \sin nx & \text{for} \; -L/2 \le x \le L/2 \\[2pt] -C \cos kx +D \sin kx & \text{for} \; x\gt L/2 \end{cases}, $$ where $\psi_E^-(-x)=-\psi_E^-(x)$. Again, $\psi_E^-$ and its first derivative have to be continuous at $x= \pm L/2$, leading to $$\begin{align} C&= B \left(\frac{n}{k} \, \cos \frac{nL}{2} \, \sin \frac{kL}{2}-\sin \frac{nL}{2} \, \cos \frac{kL}{2}    \right), \\[2pt] D&=  B \left(\frac{n}{k}\,  \cos \frac{nL}{2}\, \cos\frac{kL}{2} +\sin \frac{nL}{2} \,\sin\frac{kL}{2} \right).  \end{align}$$

Comment: Your answer correctly addressed exactly what my Python code demonstrated for me about the wave functions on the outside being non-identical. I appreciate you taking the time to write this up!

Comment: @MattHanson If you are absolutely sure that your ansatz for the wave function agrees with mine, the most probable source of your strange result for $C$ and $D$ seems to be a trivial calculational error. For your convenience, I have now included the correct expressions for $C$ and $D$ in my answer.

Comment: Again, I appreciate the assistance. Your formulas certainly disagree with mine, so I'm sure that you are right and I made some sort of error.

Comment: When I plot your solutions for the odd wave functions it works beautifully, but there seems to be a problem that I can't quite place for the even wave functions. Namely, they seem to match in their derivatives but not their actual values. Is there perhaps an error in your formulas?

Comment: @MattHanson Thanks, there was a typo in the formula for $D$. Already corrected!

Comment: It works perfectly now, thank you! I will work out how you got these solutions so that I can use this derivation in my quantum class.